# Calculated field with usage of global variable on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, variables, global, calculated-field

I have created a custom global variable using the [Custom Global Variables](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-global-variables/) plugin because I want to display this variable in various places on my website and at the same time use it inside a calculated form field.

For example, my variable is [cgv variable-name] and I want to create a form where the user will input a number in a text field e.g. 200 and the calculated field will display this: [cgv variable-name]*200

I am using Elementor if it helps.

Could you let me know which form plugin supports this? I don't mind if it is free or not.

Thank you

I have tried with CF7 and Elementor forms but it doesn't recognize the shortcode of the global variable.

Comment: For anyone having the same problem, I have found Jetformbuilder which supports the shortcodes in calculated fields.